# cannot find symbol method get(int)

Tags: java, compiler-errors

For a game i'm making I need to place a tetris-like piece on a 10x10 game board.

I want to return "occupied" if the player tries to put the piece on an occupied square on my board.

For this, I've made an initial method that returns true if the square is occupied.

```
//Return true if the cell is occupied
    public boolean isOccupied(int x, int y){
        if (board.get(x).get(y) != null){
// The problem seems to be in the line directly above
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But when i try to compile, it gives me a compiling error saying - cannot find symbol - method get(int)

I don't know why i'm getting this error or how to fix it.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does `board.get(x)` return?

Comment: board.get(x).get(y) return the coordinates of the square in the board that i'm trying to determine is occupied or unoccupied.
My board is basically a 10x10 2d array

Comment: Isn't `x` and `y` your coordinates?

Comment: Well, if you would like to get the content of a specific spot on the board, you would have to pass both values to a single method, which then returns the information about this spot. Could you please also post your code for the `Board` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your board class didn't defined get(int x) method. So instead you have to try like this ..

```
if (board[x][y] !=null)  {   // since its a 2d array (x row , y column)

return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without some of the other code around it, it's a bit hard to see what is being done, however its probably supposed to be something like this...

```
//Return true if the cell is occupied
    public boolean isOccupied(int x, int y){
        if (board.get(x,y) != null){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

What you are wanting to do is check whether the cell x,y is filled or not. You need to check the X and Y at the same time, otherwise it doesn't make sense. Your get(x,y) method would check the cell in the x,y at the same time.

The error in your code is that you're calling `get(x)` which I'm guessing returns an object for a column, and then you're trying to call `get(y)` on the column. However, the column object doesn't have a `get()` method created on it.